# UIScrollView inside UIScrollView inside UIScrollView

Tags: iphone

Sorry for the weird title, but well, that's exactly what I need. I know it can be done because I've seen other apps doing it.

Basically my app has one big scroll view with paging enabled which contains some nested scroll views in it, and it works. The problem is that I need to add another scroll view inside one of the nested scroll views. I did it, but when I try to swipe it, *sometimes* the parent scroll gets the touch. And sometimes it works. I tried tuning the `canCancelContentTouches` and `delaysContentTouches` properties, but couldn't get it working. Has anybody tried this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how it will work - upper scroll view needs to distinguish touches used to scroll on it, and touches which should be sent to inner view's. And since swipe can be used on both of scrollviews, upper one cannot calculate for sure what user is trying to do.

Comment: I ended up putting the child scroll view in the big main scroll. That's probably how that other app I saw does it (I needed it in the nested scroll because I wanted to zoom it, but apparently this is not possible).